# Getting the following error for datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following imports

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(key))
dt_formatted = dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
time_source.append(dt_formatted)
start_time = time_source[0]
t_end = start_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)
```

Getting this error,
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You converted your `datetime` object to a string and then tried to add a `timedelta` to that string.

Convert back to a `datetime` object before adding 60 minutes, and you will have no problem.

Better still, don't convert to a string (`strftime`) until you really must.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_source = []

now = datetime.now()  # 2018-02-22 19:15:03

dt_formatted = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
time_source.append(dt_formatted)
start_time = time_source[0]

t_end = datetime.strptime(start_time, '%H:%M:%S') + timedelta(minutes=60)
# 1900-01-01 20:15:03
```

Answer (score -1):

You used a `from` in your `import` statement. Now, you don't use dot notation (`datetime.timedelta`) because this refers to `datetime.datetime`.

Here is your new code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta`
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp (int (key))
dt_formatted = dt.strftime ("%H:%M:%S")
time_source.append (dt_formatted) 
start_time = time_source [0] 
t_end = start_time + timedelta (minutes = 60)
```

Comment: I had tried that earlier , but i get this error:                                                                                                                                                t_end = start_time + timedelta(minutes=60)                                     TypeError: must be str, not datetime.timedelta